# Symmetrical object won't rotate on axis evenly

Tags: rigging, objects, bones, constraints

[image]

This is a wheel with bones and constraints to help it roll and turn. I don't know what I did in the process, but my wheel no longer rotates symmetrically like it used to despite not manipulating it at all.

I've tried Origin to Geometry, Cursor to Center, and resetting the Rotation, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Is there a way to fix my wheel's rotation?

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload the blend here?
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I've just uploaded the file and it should be good to go

Comment: I have updated my answer to demonstrate it on your actual model, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set *Pivot Point* to *Median Point*

   [image]
2. Go to Edit Mode and select vertices in the middle that creates a circle so your pivot point is now at the exact center, something like at this screen:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected to move the 3D cursor to that pivot point

   [image]
4. Now exit from Edit Mode and set the object's origin to the 3D cursor by pressing the best shortcut in the universe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, select *Origin to 3D Cursor*

   [image]

---

### Whole process demonstrated on your model:

[image]